# How can i set the caret position to a specific index in passwordbox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, passwordbox, text-cursor

I need to set the cursorposition inside the passwordbox explicitly in WPF. I couldn't see the selectionstart property in passwordbox.

Any help?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can try something like this to set the selection in the PasswordBox:

```
private void SetSelection(PasswordBox passwordBox, int start, int length) {
    passwordBox.GetType().GetMethod("Select", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).Invoke(passwordBox, new object[] { start, length });
}
```

After that, call it like this to set the cursor position:

```
// set the cursor position to 2...
SetSelection( passwordBox1, 2, 0);

// focus the control to update the selection
passwordBox1.Focus();
```

Comment: I suggest to do this in PreviewTextInput, to make sure the text input is always at the end, combined with transparent CaretBrush.

Comment: Thanks a lot its working fine  ..Would you enhanged your answer more how to get caret possition from password box here ...

Answer (score 1):

No, the API for PasswordBox does not expose a way to do this.

Comment: Thanks Kent. Is there a way i can achieve this using the textbox control.

Comment: That should do it for you in a textbox: `textBox.Select(textBox.Text.Length, 0)`