# wpf passwordbox caret

Tags: wpf, caret, passwordbox, virtual-keyboard

How do I use a passwordbox control with a virtual keyboard using WPF?  With the textbox control, it's fairly simple to just move the caret to the next text position; not so with passwordbox, which doesn't expose the caret position.

Should I just derive my own?  Seems like weak sauce.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this to set the selection in the PasswordBox:

```
private void SetSelection(PasswordBox passwordBox, int start, int length) { 
    passwordBox.GetType().GetMethod("Select", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                         .Invoke(passwordBox, new object[] { start, length }); 
}
```

After that, call it like this to set the cursor position:

```
// set the cursor position to 2... or length of the password 
SetSelection( passwordBox1, 2, 0); 

// focus the control to update the selection 
passwordBox1.Focus();
```

The above answer is provided by [Andrew Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1046920/162671) and it works fine.

Comment: How would you determine the current caret position?