# How to find the cursor position in PasswordBbox in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, passwordbox

[image]

In above figure, The cursor is blinking after three text values in PasswordBox.Now i want to find, where the cursor is currently blinking.

Comment: Just to help your search : what you want to look for is "CaretIndex"...

Answer (score 0):

The PasswordBox does not expose any way to get/set the position of the carat.

It may have a non-public property that you can access via reflection (see this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990311/how-can-i-set-the-caret-position-to-a-specific-index-in-passwordbox-in-wpf)) but there's definitely no 'proper' way to do it.

Comment: I've got solution to set set the carat from your link what you posted here.But how can i get the carat with using reflection in dynamically ?