# wp7/8 PasswordBox move carret

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

Windows Phone 7/8

I'm trying to move PasswordBox caret to the end of the text when user enters the input so that he can append new chars easily.

I found this code:
[How can i set the caret position to a specific index in passwordbox in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990311/how-can-i-set-the-caret-position-to-a-specific-index-in-passwordbox-in-wpf)

But I always hit System.NullReferenceException in

```
SetSelection(LoginPasswordBox, 0, 0);
```

The StackTrace

```
at rodzic.Views.Login.SetSelection(PasswordBox passwordBox, Int32 start, Int32 length)\r\n
at rodzic.Views.Login.ShowPasswordCharsCheckBox_Unchecked(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)\r\n   
at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton.OnUnchecked(RoutedEventArgs e)\r\n   
at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton.OnIsCheckedPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)\r\n   
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.RaisePropertyChangeNotifications(DependencyProperty dp, Object oldValue, Object newValue)\r\n   
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(DependencyProperty property, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, ValueOperation operation)\r\n   
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueInternal(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, Boolean allowReadOnlySet)\r\n   
at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton.OnToggle()\r\n   
at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton.OnClick()\r\n   
at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.<OnMouseLeftButtonUp>b__3()"   string
```

Please give me a tip what can be the problem or guide me on a better way to move PasswordBox caret to the end of the text.

EDIT:

xaml

```
<PasswordBox x:Name="LoginPasswordBox" Password="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay, ElementName=PasswordInput}" Template="{StaticResource CustomPasswordBox}"/>
<TextBox x:Name="PasswordInput" Text="{Binding Password, Mode=TwoWay, ElementName=LoginPasswordBox}" Visibility="Collapsed" Style="{StaticResource CustomTextBox}"/>
<CheckBox x:Name="ShowPasswordCharsCheckBox" Content="Show password" Checked="ShowPasswordCharsCheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="ShowPasswordCharsCheckBox_Unchecked" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
```

c#

```
private void ShowPasswordCharsCheckBox_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    LoginPasswordBox.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    PasswordInput.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
// TODO not working :/
    SetSelection(LoginPasswordBox, 0, 0);
    LoginPasswordBox.Focus();
}

private void SetSelection(PasswordBox passwordBox, int start, int length)
{
    passwordBox.GetType().GetMethod("Select", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).Invoke(passwordBox, new object[] { start, length });
}
```

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint at SetSelection and see if LoginPasswordBox is null?

Comment: it's an object -> {System.Windows.Controls.PasswordBox}

Comment: @WojciechSobczyk When do you invoke SetSelection()?

Comment: @Romasz when password box gets focus, normaly the caret goes to the beginig, it's very anoying for the user

Comment: @WojciechSobczyk Is it possible that you sent me a simple example? (It might be easier to help you)

Comment: i did edit the question, still can't work it out